# Object variable not set error in vb6

Tags: vb6

```
Private m_IncidentDateRange As New MCWebServiceCOMWrapper.DateRange

Public Property Get IncidentDateRange() As MCWebServiceCOMWrapper.DateRange
    IncidentDateRange = m_IncidentDateRange
End Property
Public Property Let IncidentDateRange(ByRef vNewValue As MCWebServiceCOMWrapper.DateRange)
    Set m_IncidentDateRange = vNewValue
End Property
```

Error comes up in Get method please help

Answer (score 1):

I would check the documentation for the MCWebServiceCOMWrapper.DateRange object and see if you are required to initialized it with values before you can use it. (maybe set a beginning and end date).

Answer (score 1):

Don't you need to use "Set" there?